# X3DOM ImageTexture in a bl.ocks.org and animate it using d3.js

Tags: image, caching, d3.js, gist, x3dom

I have a X3DOM and D3.js gist and block that works fine on my local system, or on the web here: http://coderextreme.net/earth/raw/1256f90d9eea80c52d3d/index.xhtml but when I deploy to bl.ocks.org, the ImageTexture doesn't show up.  Here is my block: http://bl.ocks.org/coderextreme/1256f90d9eea80c52d3d  and gist: https://gist.github.com/coderextreme/1256f90d9eea80c52d3d  The image shows up fine in gist.

Images work on this block, but they're not ImageTexture or X3DOM http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9662ab6d5ac823c0e444  This block might be used to help answer the question (probably some kind of URL issue, but nothing's showing up in the web console that I can see on the bl.ocks.org page).

There appears to be some kind of caching on bl.ocks.org or in my web browser.  If blocks are cached, how to I flush the cache?  That is, can you as a reader of this post see the outline of the continents in the block?

If the answer is modify the URL, please assist with that.

Note that this block was built with blockbuilder.org, but I used git to upload the image.

Here's how I reference the image in X3DOM (index.xhtml):

```
<Appearance>
  <ImageTexture url='earth.png'/>
  <TextureTransform id="tt" translation="0 0" scale="0.75 1"/>
</Appearance>
```

How do I get my block and image textures to show up which display the continents?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to convert from XHTML to HTML5 and remove self-closing tags.